# Weblogic 12c - Managed Server is failing due to not reachable to admin server

Tags: weblogic12c

Can you please help me how to bring my managed server running

1)created managed server and deployed application for first time.
2)After some time i could find my Managed Server is down, So started buts failing due to below issue .

Note :Admin Server is up and running .

I have weblogic 12.2.1.3 server with two domains as domain3 and domain4

domain3 is working fine, but in domain4 Managed server is failing

To replicate issue in domain4 i have created Machine and attached the Managed server , but in monitoring Node Manager status i could find inactive .

**Can i Start Node Manager in two domains even weblogic server is same ?**

http://10.25.10.11:7001.>

http://10.15.10.23:7001.>

A MultiException has 4 exceptions.  They are:
1. weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication for user weblogic denied.
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.security.SecurityService
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.nodemanager.adminserver.NodeManagerMonitorService errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.nodemanager.adminserver.NodeManagerMonitorService

```
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:89)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:250)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Caused By: weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication for user weblogic denied.
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1158)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.postInitialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1272)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.postInitialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:586)
    at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:130)
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: [Security:090938]Authentication failure: The specified user failed to log in. weblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPAtnDelegateException: [Security:090295]caught unexpected exception, No such object
    at com.bea.common.security.utils.ExceptionHandler.throwFailedLoginException(ExceptionHandler.java:62)
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.login(LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:368)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper$1.run(LoginModuleWrapper.java:117)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper.login(LoginModuleWrapper.java:114)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

> 

Answer (score 0):

Each node manager is typically limited to a single machine. One domain can have one admin server and multiple managed servers on multiple machines.

However, you can have multiple machines configured in a single domain, so if you have two machines configured, you can have two node managers.

The following might help solve your issue:

1. Delete or make a backup of the LDAP folder under the /servers//data/ and restart the server.
2. Check if a firewall is blocking the ports. Check if the admin-URL is accessible from the managed server machine.
3. Try starting a managed server from startManagedWebLogic.cmd/sh  . Try enabling debug logging in Weblogic console -> server-name -> debug -> weblogic -> security -> atn.